# Installing Google Data Python Library

Tags: python, blogger, google-gadget

I'm trying to find a way to use Python to make gadgets for Blogger, but I'm having some trouble.

I was using this guide [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib) to install the Google data for Python, but it's not working.

I'm using Python v3.4.1, so according to the guide I should have ElementTree. However, I downloaded the Google Data Library and tried to run the setup.py script, and the command console flashed up for a fraction of a second before going away. I don't know how to get it to stay still, but I think it said something about a syntax error.

So that's my problem: trying to make Blogger gadgets with Python and I'm struggling to even install the Google Data Python library. Of course, my end goal is to make Blogger gadgets with Python, so if anyone knows a better way, I'm all ears. Thank you.

EDIT - I forgot to mention, I'm running this in Windows 7.

EDIT 2 - Alright, I just managed to run the setup script from a command prompt, and here's the error message I got:

```
C:\Users\Perry>Desktop\gdata-python-client-master\setup.py
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: what environment/OS are you running under? If in windows, try opening a cmd terminal and running your setup.py script in there. That way the terminal won't close immediately and you'll be able to read the error messages.

Comment: I'm running in Windows 7, but I don't know how to run a script in a cmd terminal.

Comment: there are a few ways to get a console. The easiest might be to hold down the windows key and press the _r_ key and type `cmd` this should bring up a terminal. then you'll have to use the _cd_ command  to change to the directory where your script is or type the full path to your script. something like `C:\users\user1\downloads\googledatalibrary\setup.py` you might have to tell it to use python to run your script... `python fullpath\toyour\script\setup.py`